# Toolbar overlapping view on Custom Behavior finish

Tags: android, toolbar, behavior, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a layout with collapsing toolbar and a smooth transition of the avatar image along with title set via behavior. However, when the CircleImageView reaches the top, it suddenly gets overlapped by the toolbar. It seems like the toolbar is getting redrawn over CircleImageView (and with a shadow) when it gets fully collapsed.

Question is: how to make CircleImageView stay on top of the toolbar?

Gif with the bug at [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nbpwommjikhpcjy/bugGif.gif?dl=0)

Here is the xml code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/ExpandedTitleText"
        app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CollapsedTitleText"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="112dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="60dp">


        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:paddingLeft="16dip"
            android:paddingRight="16dip"
            android:paddingBottom="16dip"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="bottom">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="group created by"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_secondary_white"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    tools:text="Admin name"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_secondary_white"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:id="@+id/admin"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:theme="@style/ActionBar"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/viewstub"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"  />

<package.CustomView.CircleImageView
    android:layout_width="80dip"
    android:layout_height="80dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    tools:background="@color/color_accent"
    android:id="@+id/get_avatar"
    app:layout_behavior="package.AvatarImageBehavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/color_accent"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_mode_edit_24dp"
    android:id="@+id/fab" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

AvatarImageBehavior.java - basically translates the CircleImageView to the toolbar. It depends on the stub view on the bottom of the appbar (not pretty, I know)

```
public class AvatarImageBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<CircleImageView> {

private final static float MIN_AVATAR_PERCENTAGE_SIZE   = 0.3f;
private final static int EXTRA_FINAL_AVATAR_PADDING     = 80;

private final static String TAG = "behavior";
private final Context mContext;
private float mAvatarMaxSize;

private float mFinalLeftAvatarPadding;
private float mStartPosition;
private int mStartXPosition;
private float mStartToolbarPosition;

public AvatarImageBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    mContext = context;
    init();

    mFinalLeftAvatarPadding = context.getResources().getDimension(
        R.dimen.contact_space_left);
}

private void init() {
    bindDimensions();
}

private void bindDimensions() {
    mAvatarMaxSize = mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.contact_avatar);
}

private int mStartYPosition;

private int mFinalYPosition;
private int finalHeight;
private int mStartHeight;
private int mFinalXPosition;

@Override
public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, CircleImageView child, View dependency) {
    return dependency.getId() == R.id.viewstub;
}

@Override
public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, CircleImageView child, View dependency) {
    maybeInitProperties(child, dependency);

    float toolbarY = parent.findViewById(R.id.toolbar).getY();
//        Log.w(TAG, "-----toolbar y: " + toolbarY);

    int toolbarHeight = parent.findViewById(R.id.toolbar).getHeight();
//        Log.w(TAG, "-----toolbar height: " + toolbarHeight);

//        Log.w(TAG, "dependency.getY(): " + dependency.getY());
    final int maxScrollDistance = (int)mStartToolbarPosition - toolbarHeight;
//        Log.w(TAG, "maxScrollDistance: " + maxScrollDistance);

    float expandedPercentageFactor = (dependency.getY()- toolbarHeight) / maxScrollDistance;
//        Log.w(TAG, "expandedPercentageFactor: " + expandedPercentageFactor);
    if(expandedPercentageFactor > 1f)expandedPercentageFactor = 1f;

    float distanceYToSubtract = ((mStartYPosition - mFinalYPosition)
        * (1f - expandedPercentageFactor));// + (child.getHeight()/2);
//        Log.w(TAG, "distanceYToSubtract: " + distanceYToSubtract);

    float distanceXToSubtract = ((mStartXPosition - mFinalXPosition)
        * (1f - expandedPercentageFactor)) + (child.getWidth()/2);
//        Log.w(TAG, "distanceXToSubtract: " + distanceXToSubtract);

    float heightToSubtract = ((mStartHeight - finalHeight) * (1f - expandedPercentageFactor));
//        Log.w(TAG, "heightToSubtract: " + heightToSubtract);

    child.setY(mStartYPosition - distanceYToSubtract);
//        Log.w(TAG, "child.setY: " + (mStartYPosition - distanceYToSubtract));
    child.setX(mStartXPosition - distanceXToSubtract);
//        Log.w(TAG, "child.setX: " + (mStartXPosition - distanceXToSubtract));

    int proportionalAvatarSize = (int) (mAvatarMaxSize * (expandedPercentageFactor));
//        Log.w(TAG, "proportionalAvatarSize: " + proportionalAvatarSize);

    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
    lp.width = (int) (mStartHeight - heightToSubtract);
//        Log.w(TAG, "lp.width: " + lp.width);
    lp.height = (int) (mStartHeight - heightToSubtract);
//        Log.w(TAG, "lp.height: " + lp.height);
    child.setLayoutParams(lp);

//        Log.w(TAG, "---------------------");
    return true;
}

private void maybeInitProperties(CircleImageView child, View dependency) {
    if (mStartYPosition == 0)
        mStartYPosition = (int) child.getY();
//        Log.w(TAG, "mStartYPosition: " + mStartYPosition);

    if (mFinalYPosition == 0)
        mFinalYPosition = mContext.getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.contact_final_width);
//        Log.w(TAG, "mFinalYPosition: " + mFinalYPosition);

    if (mStartHeight == 0)
        mStartHeight = child.getMeasuredHeight();
//        Log.w(TAG, "mStartHeight: " + mStartHeight);

    if (finalHeight == 0)
        finalHeight = mContext.getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.contact_final_width);
//        Log.w(TAG, "finalHeight: " + finalHeight);

    if (mStartXPosition == 0)
        mStartXPosition = (int) (child.getX() + (child.getWidth() / 2));
//        Log.w(TAG, "mStartXPosition: " + mStartXPosition);

    if (mFinalXPosition == 0)
        mFinalXPosition = mContext.getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.abc_action_bar_content_inset_material) + (finalHeight*2);
//        Log.w(TAG, "mFinalXPosition: " + mFinalXPosition);

    if (mStartToolbarPosition == 0)
        mStartToolbarPosition = dependency.getY();// 456
//        Log.w(TAG, "mStartToolbarPosition: " + mStartToolbarPosition);
}
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @PrakharMohanSrivastava No, I have not. I ended up hiding the image